# Spark job not writing RDD to file when running in amazon EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I am running a Java spark program in an AWS EMR cluster, and I have a problem writing a JavaRDD to file. I have something like the following code:

```
final JavaRDD<MyObject> javaRdd1 = // implemented here
javaRdd1.map(t -> MyClass.writeValueAsString(t)).saveAsTextFile(path1, GzipCodec.class);
```

When I run this program in spark, javaRdd1 always writes a series of empty gz files to path1. However, if I add a call to first(), like this:

```
final JavaRDD<MyObject> javaRdd1 = // implemented here
log.info("javaRdd1 " + (javaRdd1.isEmpty() ? "not here" : javaRdd1.first()));
javaRdd1.map(t -> MyClass.writeValueAsString(t)).saveAsTextFile(path1, GzipCodec.class);
```

Then the gz files written by javaRdd1 are not empty. Other then the log statement, there is no difference in logic.

I also have other JavaRdd's in the code, which I save to file in the same way. These JavaRdd's write non empty gz files; if I add the call to first(), then the size of their files increases. I do not see this behavior when running the program locally with the same arguments. Locally, the files are always printed out exactly as expected.

Note: all the inputs and outputs are stored in the HDFS.

Comment: any error log ? can you give an example of your `path1` variable ?

Comment: The only exception I see is java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Worker has already been shutdown. The path1 is passed in as a command line argument through an oozie workflow; the argument is --path1=/path/to/folder